# When to Create a New Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am learning about Task Parallelism in C#.NET 4.5, and I am a little confused about an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607.aspx). Here is the code I don't understand:

```
public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
{
  // First try to retrieve the content from cache. 
  string content;
  if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
  {
     return Task.FromResult<string>(content);
  }

  // If the result was not in the cache, download the  
  // string and add it to the cache. 
  return Task.Run(async () => // why create a new task here?
  {
     content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
     cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
     return content;
  });
}
```

Specifically, I don't understand why they are wrapping `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` in another task. Isn't `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` already running on its own thread?

Here is the way I would have coded it:

```
public static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
{
    // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
    string content;
    if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
    {
        return content;
    }

    // If the result was not in the cache, download the  
    // string and add it to the cache.
    content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
    cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
    return content;
}
```

What is the difference between the two? Which one is better?

Comment: The former works on multiple thread the latter not (since probably WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync don't use Task.Run, note that the second should be preferred since the user don't expect to spawn a new thread when using an async method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the example is specifically showing how to use `Task.FromResult`, which your second code doesn't use. That said, I disagree with the usage of `Task.Run` in the example.

I'd write it like this, myself:

```
public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
{
  // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
  string content;
  if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
  {
    return Task.FromResult(content);
  }

  // If the result was not in the cache, download the  
  // string and add it to the cache.
  return DownloadAndCacheStringAsync(address);
}

private static async Task<string> DownloadAndCacheStringAsync(string address)
{
  var content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
  cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
  return content;
}
```

Also note that the example uses the dated `WebClient`, which should be replaced with `HttpClient` in new code.

Overall, it just looks like a poor example IMO.

Comment: When you say that you would write it like this, do you mean the example OR a method like this in general? What factors would precipitate a decision to not mark a method as async when returning a Task<T> and performing async operations? Thanks.

Comment: @ach: Whenever I do an in-memory cache, I actually prefer to store the `Task<T>` itself in the cache, so I'd use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>` for a method like this in general. If I were to write an example for `Task.FromResult`, I'd use a base class or interface where the method returns a `Task` but the implementation is synchronous; I wouldn't use a cache as an example of this method. You should only mark a method as `async` if it needs to use the `await` keyword.